# countBy Method into a Function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I'm trying to write a countBy function, identical to the countBy method in Javascript. Here is what I have so far:

```
var array = [1,2,4,4,5];

function countBy(collection, func) {
    var object = {} ;
    for (var i=0;i<=0; i++) {
      for (var key in object) {
            if (func(collection[i]) === object.key) {
          object.key ++;
        } else {
          object.key = 1;
        }

      }

      }
  return object
}

alert(countBy(array, function(n) {return Math.floor(n);}));
```

What the code intends to do is search through the collection array to see if a value there matches a key in object. If it has found a match in the collection array, increment that key value by one. If it has not found one, create a new key value. Therefore, the result that should be alerted is: {4:2, 1:1, 2:1, 5:1}. But it seems like my output is  [object Object]. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i=0;i<=0; i++) {
```

This will run exactly once instead of iterating through the collection.

```
for (var key in object) {
    if (func(collection[i]) === object.key) {
```

This does the wrong thing; you should call `func` only once in each iteration and then look up the result of the function call in your object.

```
object.key ++;
```

This doesn't do what you want; it's better to use the array dereference operator instead.

```
function countBy(collection, func) 
{
  var object = Object.create(null);

  collection.forEach(function(item) {
    var key = func(item);
    if (key in object) {
      ++object[key];
    } else {
      object[key] = 1;
    }
  });

  return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countby(arr, selector) {
    selector = selector ?? (x => x) // default is identity
    const f = (acc, x) => {
        let k = selector(x);
        acc[k] = (acc[k] ?? 0) + 1;
        return acc
    }
    return arr.reduce(f, {})
};

let r

r = countby([2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4])
console.log(r)

r = countby([{a:2}, {a:3, b:"bunny"}, {a:2}], (x => x.a))
console.log(r)
```